# How to check whether a character is in a set of characters, or out of that set, in Java?

Tags: java

I want to compare a character whether it is in the given set characters, or out of that set, in java. 
--> is char 'c' in any of the sets [A-Z]or[a-z]or[0-9]

Or

--> is char 'c' out of the sets [A-Z]or[a-z]or[0-9]

Comment: by running the regex with that as param?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex with

```
boolean isAMatch = Character.toString(ch).matches("[A-Za-z01]")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/), you can use its [`CharMatcher`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html) class:

```
CharMatcher azLowerMatcher = CharMatcher.inRange('a','z');
CharMatcher azUpperMatcher = CharMatcher.inRange('A','Z');
CharMatcher zeroOneMatcher = CharMatcher.anyOf("01");
CharMatcher set = azLowerMatcher.or(azUpperMatcher).or(zeroOneMatcher);

boolean isInSet = set.matches('c');
```

This tool is specifically built for your use case.